# How to inject a number into HTML from a list?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

What is the most convenient way of injecting a number into the HTML of the site (using Chrome Extensions), when the given parameter is found in the website's code? For example we have a list:

- www.newsweek.com, hf-title, 2
- www.aaa.com, yzs, 1
- www.ccc.com, abc, 123

When we find "hf-title" on the website www.newseek.com then number "2" is inserted next to the found paragraph on the website in the browser. When we find "abc" in the code of the website www.ccc.com then number "123" is inserted next to the table, and so on.

There cannot be any connection to the database, just javascript.
The list that is going to be used will be hundreds of rows long, so it is really problematic to use switch statement.

The source table has to be located in the Google Chrome extension files on the PC. The information should be looked for when (or shortly after) the site is being opened.

Example of the source code:

```
<h2 class="hf-title">
    <a href="/four-nato-allies-deny-" class="article-link">Four NATO Allies Deny Ukraine<span class="overlay article-overlay"></span></a>
</h2>
<div class="hf-summary">
    NATO officials have previously said...  </div>
</div>
```

We add simply

```
<a> 2 </a>
```

at the end.

Any ideas? ;)

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: I've added more information. Is it clear enaugh now?

Comment: No. Where is the table located? On the site you're detecting or in a separate page? When do you look up the information, when the corresponding site is opened?

Comment: I've added the explenation at the end of the question. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will likely need to do is find all of the text nodes on the page. From there you can begin editing them. The 'modifyTextNodes' function is an example of using a TreeWalker to do this. It is a very efficient method for traversing the DOM.

```
var arr = [{url:"www.newsweek.com", string:"hf-title", value:"2"},
           {url:"www.aaa.com", string:"yzs", value:"1"},
           {url:"www.ccc.com", string:"abc", value:"123"}];

function modifyTextNodes() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
  var walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n = walk.nextNode()) {
    modifyNode(n);
  }
}

function modifyNode(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && node.parentNode != undefined && (val = node.nodeValue.trim())) {
    var addToEnd = "";
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      if (document.baseURI.indexOf(arr[i].url) > -1 && val.indexOf(arr[i].string) > -1) {
        addToEnd  += arr[i].value;
      }
    }
  }
  if (addToEnd) {
    node.nodeValue += addToEnd;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if it is elements that you are trying to find, you could use querySelectorAll to find  all the matching elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class='" + arr[i].string + "']");
```

In this case 'modifyAllNodes' would look like

```
function modifyAllNodes() {
  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (document.baseURI.indexOf(arr[i].url) > -1) {
      var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("[class='" + arr[i].string + "']");
      modifyNodes(nodes, arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

function modifyNodes(nodes, arrEl) {
  for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    if (node.nodeValue.indexOf(arrEl.string) > -1) {
      node.nodeValue += arrEl.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to know the structure of the list you are trying to "hack", which means the ID or class names. Afterwards, in your JS check each record of that list if its content matches the string you pass to and then do a `.append()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The question here is what is the most efficient/elegant way in JS to check each record of the list and pass the number.

Comment: `$(Classname for record + ":contains('" + value + "')").parents(parent class name).append(new thing you want to add)`